# Cookie alternative for standalone HTML application converted by PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, session, cordova, mobile, cookies

I have a **dynamic HTML** document that does not contain any external resources (no images, css and scripts are coded inside of document). Using **PhoneGap** I have converted this document into standalone **Android** application. As this HTML document is local application with no internet connectivity, using cookies is unfortunately not an option. I need to save/load application status to allow user to continue to use/run the application later. Using **cookies** was a working solution in Windows environment using IE browser, but because most of browsers **do not allow** to use cookies **for local files**, this solution is not supported by browser on my Android device (default browser of Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0). What is an **alternative solution** to allow save/load some JavaScript/jQuery variable(s) for later use?

Comment: How about HTML5 local storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at HTML5's localStorage. It gives you all the features of cookies, and more, in a simple key-value store. Ex:

```
localStorage["myJQVar"] = JSON.stringify(someJQVar);
```

Then, next time your app launches:

```
someJQVar = JSON.parse(localStorage["myJQVar"])
```

Local storage is now the preferred way to do local storage of data anyway, and some people also block most cookies for privacy reasons, so this is the way to go.

Comment: +1 :: Thank your for your prompt response (comment followed by answer).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

This allows you to store (string-)data in the browser, without the need to submit anything (like with cookies).

To encode your data from and to this string, use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Simple example:

```
// save to localStorage
localStorage.yourData = JSON.stringify( settings );

// load from localStorage
var settings = JSON.parse( localStorage.yourData );
```

Comment: +1 :: Thank you. Because Linuxios came with this solution first (by posting comment followed by answer later), to be fair I have accepted his answer.